# How to verify programmically that first lambda has established connection with second lambda successfully - Nodejs AWS-lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, async-await

I have two lambda fns. First tries to call second lambda as shown below,

**First lambda code**,

```
         try {
            const requestId = `${uuidv4()}` // generates guid. It just generates GUID without knowing if call was successful or not.

            lambda.invoke({
                FunctionName: `download-lambda-fn`,
                InvocationType: 'Event',
                Payload: JSON.stringify({
                    path: `${APP_CONSTANTS.API_ENDPOINT_PREFIX}/download`,
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                    body: JSON.stringify(req?.body),
                    httpMethod: "POST"
                }),
            }).promise();  // This is fire n forget call. Don't want to wait for the response from second lambda
        
          console.log(`Your requestId : ${requestId} is being processed`); // I want to print this message only when connect has been established successfully or first lambda has successfully called second lambda but don't wait for second lambda response.

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('error occured');
        }
```

**Problem:**

**calling second lambda for the first time:**

after deployment, whenever first lambda calls second lambda for the first time, assuming generated GUID is `1xxx-xxx-xx-xx1`, in second lambda's `**cloudwatch**` nothing logs no matter how many minutes, hours I wait.

**subsequent calls to second lambda**

If I call second lambda again, it generated new GUID `2xxx-xxx-xx-xx2` but problem is, it executes `1xxx-xxx-xx-xx1` request and I can see logs getting printed for `1xxx-xxx-xx-xx1` and not for `2xxx-xxx-xx-xx2` and it goes on.

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to create GUID only when first lambda makes connection to second lambda. KEEP IN MIND, it is fire and forget mechanism. I don't want my first lambda to wait for response from second lambda. In such scenario, how can I make sure that call has been made to second lambda (and generate GUID if connection is successful).

Comment: I'm not a Node person, but I suspect your Lambda function is exiting before the promise has been fulfilled. Later, when the Lambda environment 'wakes up' again due to a new invocation, it probably continues and actually calls the second Lambda function. Something to do with `promise` vs `await`, or some similar Node stuff.

Comment: Yes maybe correct but need a way to confirm that connection has been established in nodejs.

Comment: try to put `await lambda.invoke` infront of your call